# How to track multiple domains in google analytics in for a short period of time?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a parent website **b.website.com** which is a subdomain of **website.com**. We have a ga code created for **b.website.com**. Now I want to track another domain for a short duration of time, **newdomain.com**.

Tracking code in **b.website.com**:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['newdomain.com']); // Need help here
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

According to google analytics I should have the following code in **newdomain.com**,

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['website.com']); // Need help here
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

What should I add near autoLink, **b.website.com** or just **a.website.com** as I do not want any link between **newdomain.com** and the parent **website.com** which has its own tracking code.

Or is there a better way to do this as my need is to temporarily track the flow from b.website.com to **newdomain.com**.

Comment: Your example code is for cross-domain tracking. It is only needed if you want to track sessions that switch between both domains in a single property. Can you confirm that this is what you want (because the rest of your question does not sound like its about cross domain tracking) ?

Comment: I want to track how many users go from **b.website.com** to **newdomain.com**, so that I can generate a report.